# this.authenticationManager" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth/")
public class LoginController {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider() {
        return jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    UserRepository users;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody AuthBody data) {
        try {
            String username = data.getEmail();
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, data.getPassword()));
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, this.users.findByEmail(username).getRoles());
            Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("username", username);
            model.put("token", token);
            // return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(model.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid email/password supplied");
        }
    }
    }
```

My webSecurityConfig :

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean( name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean() ;
    }
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/auth/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/products/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint()).and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
        http.cors();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Unauthorized");
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }
}
```

I'm alaway getting null pointer exception on `authentiticationMnager.authenticate`!

I'm using spring security v 1.1.1 release and jjwt version 0.9.1 .

The authenticationManager is always null.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Please [edit] the question and remove the nonsense-text. --- Why would you expect that the `AuthenticationManager` is anything but `null`?

Comment: There is no `@Autowired` on that field so how should Spring know it should autowire that field?

Answer (score 0):

this is resolved .

My mistake is a wrong package path .

Comment: Please mark this as solved or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `@Autowired`
I had the same problem. After adding it cleared.

Answer (score -2):

can you try this annotation in WebSecurityConfig class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this will fix the problem at hand. Enabling global method security will not automagically activate injection without an annotation or constructor.

Comment: and add enableWebSecurity annotation. I think it is working. The owner will say the result. If you have a better answer please tell us

Comment: i'm still having the same problem even when i add those annotation in websecurityConfig

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)" because "this.authenticationManager" is null

Comment: hello, if i add this autowired on authenticationManager i'll get this error : Field authenticationManager in com.geoteck.controller.LoginController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.